# android studio sqlite method error

Tags: java, android, sql

I have this code:

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class ConnectDB { 
SQLiteDatabase db = openDatabase("/assets/products.sqlite",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    }
```

I am getting an error that openDatabase method not found.
How can I connect to this sqlite file and get the contents?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `ConnectDB` class doesn't extend the `SQLiteDatabase` class so it doesn't have the `openDatabase(...)` method

Comment: @Titus I am getting these errors.

Error:(8, 33) error: cannot inherit from final SQLiteDatabase

Error:(8, 8) error: SQLiteDatabase() is not public in SQLiteDatabase; cannot be accessed from outside package

Error:(10, 64) error: cannot find symbol variable MODE_PRIVATE

Comment: If you can't extend that class, create an instance of it and call this method on that instance. From the docs, it seems that `openDatabase(...)`  is `static` so you can do this `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...)`

Comment: @Titus Nothing..

Error:(9, 8) error: ConnectDB is not abstract and does not override abstract method onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase,int,int) in SQLiteOpenHelper

I added the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods but I am still getting errors. Why is it so difficult to open an sqlite file??

Comment: I dont understant a thing.. anyway thank you!

Comment: Try this `SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...)`

Comment: @Titus hmm this seems to work but what am I supposed to put at "MODE_PRIVATE"? right now it says "cannot resolve symbol MODE_PRIVATE" 

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/asstesproducts.sqlite",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

Comment: Try this `SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/assets/products.sqlite",SQLiteDatabase.MODE_PRIVATE,null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your database is packaged as an asset in `assets/` in your project, that is not a file on the filesystem of the device. [Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to unpack the packaged database and put it on the filesystem for your use.